# Is this kind of masking possible with UIImage or CGImage API in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, masking

I have an UIImage with some text and would like to apply pattern UIImage as masking. Is this possible ? 
I understand that with UILabel we can get this kind of gradient using CAGradientLayer. But can this be done if the source is an UIImage ?

The image may have some symbols/pictures etc other than regular characters and hence UIImage. Also i could reuse the image by applying different masking pattern depending on the context.

[is this possible ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agszf.png)

Appreciate your help.

EDIT: Thanks for all your answers.
I understand applying the gradient to a text label or creating an image that has text.
But my goal is to get this.--> [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9jyg.png)

i.e. i have a png with some drawing like a flower with transparent background. I want to apply the gradient to the object inside that picture at runtime with a gradient.png as shown in the picture above. Is that possible with masking ?

Thanks

Comment: A mockup (e.g. Made in photoshop) of what you're trying to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: @kris Here is the link..[link]http://i.imgur.com/Agszf.png Its actually the link "is this possible".. Sorry for the confusing word.. I should have just left the link..

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you should be able to use CGImageMaskCreate:

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}
```

For a longer discussion check out the comment thread here:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

Comment: I have provided the mockup of what i am trying to achieve in above comment. Here is the link [link]http://i.imgur.com/Agszf.png. I have tried the above method of using CGImageMaskCreate(), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is :)

```
textField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"rainbowGradient.png"]];
```

If you want heavy control, Jason Whyne's idea might work. But I like this one, because it's about 8 lines shorter.

Comment: true. I do use this in my application for labels. But in my case the text is inside an image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's just another way to draw an image of text masking something. It's based on `kCGBlendModeSourceIn` blending mode: you draw text on a clear background and then draw the fill all over the place.

```
NSString *theString = ...;
UIFont *theFont = ...;
CGSize stringSize = [theString sizeWithFont:theFont];

// The background must be clear (fully transparent), hence NO as the 2nd argument
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(stringSize, NO, 0);
[theString drawAtPoint:CGPointZero withFont:theFont];
// This effectively colorizes the image. Use a pattern color...
[patternColor set];
UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(CGRectMake(0, 0, stringSize.width, stringSize.height), kCGBlendModeSourceIn);
// ... or an image:
[patternImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, stringSize.width, stringSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeSourceIn alpha:1.0f];

UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

sample using mask is fine and works well, but You are leaking.
CGImageMaskCreate and CGImageCreateWithMask do allocate (following "create" -> retain rule)
so You should release mask & image after using:

```
CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
UIImage * result =  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
CGImageRelease(mask);
CGImageRelease(masked);
return result;
```

As per ADC docs:
...
Return Value
A Quartz bitmap image mask. You are responsible for releasing this object by calling CGImageRelease.